# Calculating unique ID number from a set of bitmasked tiles

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, game-engine, bitmask

I'm writing a match3-style game where the player needs to match tiles with three or more of the same type and I'm thinking what is the best method to recognize the shapes without writing a monstrosity of switch/if-else statements. Because in my game the player should be able to match many different shapes that consist of at least 3 or more vertical and/or horizontal shapes, for example ...

```
###

#
#
#

#
#
###

###
 #
 #

 #
###
 #

##
##
##
```

And any variation of these (the last one is a block).
I'm currently using a floodfill algorithm that not only find all the connected tiles but also assigns a bitmask depending on if and what connections the tile has to its surrounding tiles (it's based on the bitmasking explained at http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-match-puzzle-shapes-using-bitmasks--gamedev-11759

Here is the relevant code part for this (Unity, C#):

```
    internal const int BITMASK_NONE = 0;
    internal const int BITMASK_TOP = 1;
    internal const int BITMASK_RIGHT = 2;
    internal const int BITMASK_BOTTOM = 4;
    internal const int BITMASK_LEFT = 8;

    internal const int BITMASK_CORNER_TOP_RIGHT = 3;
    internal const int BITMASK_CORNER_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 6;
    internal const int BITMASK_CORNER_TOP_LEFT = 9;
    internal const int BITMASK_CORNER_BOTTOM_LEFT = 12;

    internal const int BITMASK_THREEWAY_TOP = 11;
    internal const int BITMASK_THREEWAY_RIGHT = 7;
    internal const int BITMASK_THREEWAY_BOTTOM = 14;
    internal const int BITMASK_THREEWAY_LEFT = 13;

    internal const int BITMASK_VERTICAL_LINE = 5;
    internal const int BITMASK_HORIZONTAL_LINE = 10;

    internal const int BITMASK_CROSS = 15;


    private Dictionary<int, GridCell> FindConnectedCells(GridCell cell)
    {
        var connectedCells = new Dictionary<int, GridCell>(size);

        cell.isFlagged = true;

        _cellStack.Clear();
        _cellStack.Push(cell);

        while (_cellStack.Count > 0)
        {
            cell = _cellStack.Pop();

            /* Assign bitmask to cell. */
            if (cell.Equals(cell.top)) cell.bitmask |= BITMASK_TOP;
            if (cell.Equals(cell.bottom)) cell.bitmask |= BITMASK_BOTTOM;
            if (cell.Equals(cell.right)) cell.bitmask |= BITMASK_RIGHT;
            if (cell.Equals(cell.left)) cell.bitmask |= BITMASK_LEFT;

            connectedCells.Add(cell.id, cell);

            if (FlagMatchingCell(cell, cell.top)) _cellStack.Push(cell.top);
            if (FlagMatchingCell(cell, cell.bottom)) _cellStack.Push(cell.bottom);
            if (FlagMatchingCell(cell, cell.right)) _cellStack.Push(cell.right);
            if (FlagMatchingCell(cell, cell.left)) _cellStack.Push(cell.left);
        }

        return connectedCells;
    }
```

This uses a stack-based flood-fill. In any case every tile (or cell) ends of with a specific bitmask value between 1 and 15 and I want to calculate a unique number from these and a couple of other numbers (e.g. how many tiles are in the shape, how many horizontal/vertical tiles it has, etc.) but so far I haven't managed to calculate it to produce really unique numbers. Every now and then it comes up with different shapes that have the same calculated number.

Another problem with this approach is that it can't detect whether all tiles of the shape are valid or not. Consider this shape:

```
 #
****
```

It should be recognized only as a shape of four horizontal tiles but it would also include that additional tile on top.

So my question is: What is another good approach for recognizing all these different shapes? Basically the idea of calculating a unique number for every shape doesn't seem so bad because it seems very elegant but there is then still the problem with the odd shapes like above.

Comment: Each shape is a game object?

For uniqueId you can use this:
uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

Comment: I understand you wish identical IDs for identical shapes, even if they're in different grid locations and/or rotated/flipped. I'd try to use some kind of bit serialization expressing where and how to turn or branch from a given starting point. Exact serialization method would require an exact definition of what a "shape" is (e.g. are dead ends allowed or has it to be a cycle?) and when shapes are "identical" (e.g. rotations). In any case, this will quickly get too long to be considered a "number" in the usual sense and should probably be treated as a bitstream, not an integer number.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I came up with a simple algorithm that creates unique numbers. But the problem is actually another one and I started to doubt that using a flood-fill in the first place is a good idea.